# ifstream breaks after reading a file 3 times

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, vector

Im picking up values from a .txt file using `ifstream`. i am also using `windows` library to read all files in a folder, that is loop over until the end of folder is reached. In this loop I am reading values from a txt file and adding it to a matrix using `push_back`.

Here is the section of code under question:

```
Mat trainme(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1); 
Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1); //1d matrix with 32fc1 is requirement of normalbayesclassifier class



hTrain = FindFirstFile(full_path, &TrainData);
if (hTrain != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{

    ifstream file("c:\\222\\labels.txt");
    string line;

    do {

        strcpy(loc,DirSpec);

        Mat img = imread(strcat(loc,TrainData.cFileName), 0);
        cout<<"Processing file:  "<<TrainData.cFileName<<endl;

        if (!img.data){
        cout << "Image data not loaded properly:  " <<TrainData.cFileName<< endl;
        cin.get();
        }
        vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
        features->detect(img, keypoints);
        if(keypoints.empty()) cout<<"Cannot find keypoints in image:  "<<TrainData.cFileName<<endl;
        Mat bowDescriptor;
        bowDE.compute(img, keypoints, bowDescriptor);
        trainme.push_back(bowDescriptor);
        getline(file, line);

        labels.push_back(line);

        strcpy(loc,"");
        } while( FindNextFile(hTrain,&TrainData));
}
```

The problem arises at the line `labels.push_back(line);` after 3 loops. I mean the file is read 3 times and after that the error: `Access violation writing location`. And points to this line in `memcpy.asm`:

> ```
>     mov     [edi],al        ;U - put byte in destination
> ```

I cannot figure out why it fails. I thought it may be a problem transferring `string` format so I used `float value = atof(line)` but that gave an error that it cannot convert from string format and it can only take the old c style string.

Here is what is contained in the labels.txt

```
1
2
2
2
1
2
2
2
```

Thank you for looking.

Update: I tried moving the file reading out of the main loop and used `while(file.good())` But I still get the same error at the same spot. I have no idea why.

```
string line;
ifstream file("c:\\222\\labels.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    while (file.good() )
    {
    getline (file,line);
    labels.push_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of type `Mat`?

Comment: @phonetagger Its a function of opencv, as in ``cv::Mat``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I managed to get it solved... =/

The problem was here: `labels.push_back(line);`

I think adding `std::string` to Mat using `push_back` is not possible.

I solved it by converting the string to float using `atof`.

```
getline (file,line);
float label = atof(line.c_str());
labels.push_back(label);
```